# Starting a Grizzly HTTP server on a fargate container

Tags: java, docker, aws-fargate, httpserver, grizzly

```java
String baseUri = http://127.0.0.1:8080/abc
HttpServer grizzlyServer = startServer(baseUri);
while (grizzlyServer.isStarted())
{
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    loopCount++;
    loopCount = loopCount%60;
    if (loopCount == 0)
    {
        logger.finest("I am still Running");
    }
}
try {
    grizzlyServer.shutdown().get();

} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.warning("Exception stopping HTTP Server: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());       
}

/**
 * Starts the grizzly HTTP server for providing the REST capabilities
 *
 * @param baseUri the base uri of the server
 * @return the grizzly http server
 */
public static HttpServer startServer(String baseUri) 
{
    
    // create a resource config that scans for JAX-RS resources and providers in the given package
    final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("com.api");
        
    rc.property(ServerProperties.WADL_FEATURE_DISABLE, true); // disable WADL as we don't use it and it generates runtime warnings
        
    // Register the provider binder - implements jakarta.ws.rs.core.Feature. Then we have some other classes with @Path and @GET annotations, and the provider here is @Inject-ed, so we have access to it.
    rc.register(new ServiceProviderBinder());
        
    // create and start a new instance of grizzly http server
    // exposing the Jersey application at BASE_URI
    HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(baseUri), rc);
    Logger l = Logger.getLogger("org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler");
    l.setLevel(Level.FINE);
    l.setUseParentHandlers(false);
    ConsoleHandler ch = new ConsoleHandler();
    ch.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    l.addHandler(ch);
    return server;
}
```

I can use this approach to start up the server locally, or in a docker container than is run locally using `docker-compose up`.

If, however, I then deploy this same container to fargate through an ECS Task Definition and service, I get the following in Cloudwatch:

`jakarta.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Failed to start Grizzly HTTP server: Address already in use`

I get the same if I use 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1.

My Task definition configuration contains a port mapping 8080:8080 -

[![task definition mapping][1]][1]

and my Dockerfile is as follows (with the details passed in from docker-compose):

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:21.0.1_12-jdk
ARG SERVICE_NAME
ARG APP_DIR=/opt/app
RUN mkdir -p ${APP_DIR}
COPY ${SERVICE_NAME}.sh ${APP_DIR}
COPY dependencies ${APP_DIR}/dependencies
COPY ${SERVICE_NAME}.jar ${APP_DIR}
COPY ${SERVICE_NAME}.awstest.properties ${APP_DIR}

USER root

RUN chmod -R 777 ${APP_DIR}

# When the container starts, run the svt startup script
ENV SERVICESCRIPT=${APP_DIR}/${SERVICE_NAME}.sh
CMD exec $SERVICESCRIPT
```

Task definition:

````json
{
    "family": "appname",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "appnameQP",
            "image": "012345678901.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/appname:appnameQP",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "8080",
                    "containerPort": 8080,
                    "hostPort": 8080,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": false,
            "environment": [],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "containerName": "initkafka",
                    "condition": "COMPLETE"
                }
            ],
            "ulimits": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/appname",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-west-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "systemControls": []
        },
        {
            "name": "appnamerd",
            "image": "012345678901.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/appname:appnamerd",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [],
            "essential": false,
            "environment": [],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "containerName": "initkafka",
                    "condition": "COMPLETE"
                }
            ],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/appname",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-west-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "systemControls": []
        },
        {
            "name": "appnamesm",
            "image": "012345678901.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/appname:appnamesm",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [],
            "essential": false,
            "environment": [],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "containerName": "initkafka",
                    "condition": "COMPLETE"
                }
            ],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/appname",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-west-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "systemControls": []
        },
        {
            "name": "appnameRT",
            "image": "012345678901.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/appname:appnameRT",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [],
            "essential": false,
            "environment": [],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "containerName": "mosquitto",
                    "condition": "START"
                },
                {
                    "containerName": "initkafka",
                    "condition": "COMPLETE"
                }
            ],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/appname",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-west-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "systemControls": []
        },
        {
            "name": "appnamePS",
            "image": "012345678901.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/appname:appnamePS",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [],
            "essential": false,
            "environment": [],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "containerName": "mosquitto",
                    "condition": "START"
                },
                {
                    "containerName": "initkafka",
                    "condition": "COMPLETE"
                }
            ],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/appname",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-west-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "systemControls": []
        },
        {
            "name": "appnameFF",
            "image": "012345678901.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/appname:appnameFF",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [],
            "essential": false,
            "environment": [],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "containerName": "initkafka",
                    "condition": "COMPLETE"
                }
            ],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/appname",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-west-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "systemControls": []
        },
        {
            "name": "kafka",
            "image": "012345678901.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/appname:kafka",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "9092",
                    "containerPort": 9092,
                    "hostPort": 9092,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "KAFKA_CFG_NUM_PARTITIONS",
                    "value": "1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP",
                    "value": "CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT"
                },
                {
                    "name": "KAFKA_CFG_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE",
                    "value": "true"
                },
                {
                    "name": "KAFKA_CFG_NUM_IO_THREADS",
                    "value": "8"
                },
                {
                    "name": "KAFKA_CFG_SOCKET_SEND_BUFFER_BYTES",
                    "value": "102400"
                },
                {
                    "name": "KAFKA_CFG_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY",
                    "value": "3000"
                },
                {
                    "name": "KAFKA_CFG_SOCKET_REQUEST_MAX_BYTES",
                    "value": "104857600"
                },
                {
                    "name": "KAFKA_CFG_NUM_NETWORK_THREADS",
                    "value": "8"
                },
                {
                    "name": "KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT",
                    "value": "127.0.0.1:2181"
                },
                {
                    "name": "KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS",
                    "value": "PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093,EXTERNAL://:9094"
                },
                {
                    "name": "KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS",
                    "value": "PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9094"
                }
            ],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "containerName": "zookeeper",
                    "condition": "START"
                }
            ],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/appname",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-west-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "systemControls": []
        },
        {
            "name": "initkafka",
            "image": "012345678901.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/appname:initkafka",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [],
            "essential": false,
            "entryPoint": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c"
            ],
            "command": [
                "# blocks until kafka is reachable",
                "kafka-topics --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --list",
                "echo -e 'Creating appname Kafka Topics'",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen1 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config cleanup.policy=compact",
                "delete --config retention.ms=604800000 --config delete.retention.ms=604800000",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen2 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config cleanup.policy=compact",
                "delete --config retention.ms=604800000 --config delete.retention.ms=604800000",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen3 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config cleanup.policy=compact",
                "delete --config retention.ms=604800000 --config delete.retention.ms=604800000",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen4 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config cleanup.policy=compact",
                "delete --config retention.ms=604800000 --config delete.retention.ms=604800000",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen5 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config cleanup.policy=compact",
                "delete --config retention.ms=172800000 --config delete.retention.ms=172800000",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen6 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config retention.ms=200000000 --config delete.retention.ms=200000000",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen7 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config cleanup.policy=compact",
                "delete --config retention.ms=172800000 --config delete.retention.ms=172800000",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen8 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config cleanup.policy=compact",
                "delete --config retention.ms=60480000 --config delete.retention.ms=60480000",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen9 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config cleanup.policy=compact",
                "delete --config retention.ms=604800000 --config delete.retention.ms=604800000",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen10 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config cleanup.policy=compact",
                "delete --config retention.ms=604800000 --config delete.retention.ms=604800000",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen11 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config cleanup.policy=compact",
                "delete --config retention.ms=604800000 --config delete.retention.ms=604800000",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen12 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config cleanup.policy=compact",
                "delete --config retention.ms=604800000 --config delete.retention.ms=604800000",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen13 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 6 --config cleanup.policy=compact",
                "delete --config retention.ms=60480000 --config delete.retention.ms=60480000",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen14 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config retention.ms=60480000 --config delete.retention.ms=60480000",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen15 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config retention.ms=604800 --config delete.retention.ms=604800",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen15 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config retention.ms=604800 --config delete.retention.ms=604800",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen16 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config retention.ms=604800 --config delete.retention.ms=604800",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen17 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config cleanup.policy=compact",
                "delete --config retention.ms=604800000 --config delete.retention.ms=604800000",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen18 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config cleanup.policy=compact",
                "delete --config retention.ms=604800000 --config delete.retention.ms=604800000",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen19 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 6 --config retention.ms=172800000 --config delete.retention.ms=172800000",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen20 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 100 --config retention.ms=6048000 --config delete.retention.ms=6048000",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen21 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config retention.ms=604800 --config delete.retention.ms=604800",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen22 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 6 --config cleanup.policy=compact",
                "delete --config retention.ms=172800000 --config delete.retention.ms=172800000",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen23 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config cleanup.policy=compact",
                "delete --config retention.ms=172800000 --config delete.retention.ms=172800000",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen24 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config retention.ms=60480000 --config delete.retention.ms=60480000",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen25 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config cleanup.policy=compact",
                "delete --config retention.ms=172800000 --config delete.retention.ms=172800000",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic topicnamen26 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config retention.ms=200000000 --config delete.retention.ms=200000000",
                "echo -e 'successfully created the following topics:'",
                "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --list"
            ],
            "environment": [],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "containerName": "kafka",
                    "condition": "START"
                }
            ],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/appname",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-west-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "systemControls": []
        },
        {
            "name": "zookeeper",
            "image": "012345678901.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/appname:zookeeper",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "2181",
                    "containerPort": 2181,
                    "hostPort": 2181,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "essential": false,
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN",
                    "value": "yes"
                }
            ],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/appname",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-west-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "systemControls": []
        },
        {
            "name": "mosquitto",
            "image": "012345678901.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/appname:mosquitto",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "1883",
                    "containerPort": 1883,
                    "hostPort": 1883,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "essential": false,
            "environment": [],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/appname",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-west-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "systemControls": []
        }
    ],
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::012345678901:role/appname_Fargate_ECS_Role",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::012345678901:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "8192",
    "memory": "16384",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    }
}```

where appnameQP is the container that is failing.

What do I need to change in my configuration, either in code, Docker or AWS, in order to get this working? Why is port 8080 already in use on the fargate container?


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DClEW.png
````

Comment: I think the issue may be that you are trying to bind the server to `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`. I would try changing that to `0.0.0.0`. If that doesn't work, I suggest posting your entire task definition JSON in your question.

Comment: I've tried that, but same issue. Presuming I should keep the `http://`? relevant part of JSON added

Comment: I asked to see the full task definition, because I wondered if you had another container running, among other things. It looks like you do indeed have another container running in the task, but you didn't include the details. I'm guessing that other container is binding to port `8080` which is causing this error.

Comment: I've actually got 10 containers total, but none of them are explicitly binding to that port. I'll try and put the full definition with any sensitive details changed

Comment: Multiple containers on Fargate will bind to a single network interface. Even if you don't have the port mappings defined, the containers could still be starting up services that bind to those ports. Is there any reason you absolutely have to use port `8080` or could you change your app to use a different port?